# Can a data file be used as a field in a function?

Tags: python, function

I am making a program that iterates through a data file and looks through for a target sequence. Right now I am only using 2 files as test cases, but I want to expand it to be able to use 15-20 files. I don't want to define this many repeats of the same function just to encapsulate each file, so is there any way where i can input which file that i read?

```
# looks for a target sequence within sequence   
def targetSequence1(target):
    print("looking for target sequence in data set 1", target)
    counter= 0
    length = len(target)
    for element in data:
        if(data[counter:counter+length] == target):
            print(" match found at", counter, counter+length)
        counter+=1

# same as targetSequence1, but for the other document  
def targetSequence2(target):
    print("looking for target sequence in data set 2", target)
    counter= 0
    length = len(target)
    for element in data1:
        if(data1[counter:counter+length] == target):
            print(" match found at", counter, counter+length)
        counter+=1
```

these functions both work- but i want to be able to merge both of these programs so that i can pick which data file i want to analyze

Comment: What is the point of `for element in data:` when you never use `element`?

Comment: You already know how to do it; pass the data you want to search through as a parameter to the function instead of using global variables. Just like you're doing with the target.

Comment: Use `def targetSequence(target, data)` as @molbdnilo suggests and get the function to return your result